# Ignoring Javascript, CSS and image files routing in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, .net-4.0, url-routing

I've turned Stack Overflow up and down, but, unfortunately, none of the answers helped me.

I have a web app that works perfectly on my local PC using IIS provided by the Visual Studio, but when I deploy this app to the server only the CSS is displayed properly.

Folder structure for files is as follows:

- Root (this folder is named **Knowledge Management** on the server)

  - **CSS**
  - **JS**
  - **Media**
  - **Uploads**

    - Documents
    - Images
    - Users

My code, at least for Master page head section looks like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <link href="CSS/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/JS/jQuery203Min.js"></script>
    <script src="/JS/jQueryUI1103Min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

However, browser generates it like this:

```
<head>
    <link href="../../CSS/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="JS/jQuery203Min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jQueryUI1103Min.js"></script>    
    <script src="/JS/HomeArticles.js"></script>
</head>
```

The problem is that besides CSS neither none of the files in JS folder and none of the files in Media or Uploads folders and subfolder doesn't generate properly.

The thing is if I add "slash" in front of the image src attribute the image gets location `http://localhost/Media/Discussion.png` and if I don't add "slash" then the image location is `http://localhost/Uploads/Users/HrvojeFadiga.jpg` when it should be `http://localhost/Knowledge%20Management/Uploads/Users/HrvojeFadiga.jpg`

Here is a sample of code with images:

```
<div class="profileInfoWrapper">
    <img src="/Uploads/Users/<%=article.User.PhotoLocation %>" />
    <span class="postInfo">
        <img src="/Media/Rating.png" /><%= GetArticleRating(article.idArticle) %>
    </span>
    <span class="postInfo">
        <img src="/Media/Visitors.png" /><%= GetArticleViews(article.idArticle) %>
    </span>
    <span class="postInfo">
        <img src="/Media/Comments.png" /><%= GetArticleComments(article.idArticle) %>
    </span>
</div>
```

FYI, Global.asax doesn't contain any rules for ignoring file routes except for .axd files which is added by default.

Comment: "The thing is if I add "slash" in front of the image src attribute" - Can you show the code which includes the image element? Also, if you remove the "/" from the script src attribute, do those links still not work?

Comment: @Fresh I've added the code with image element. Removing slash doesn't help. I don't know if there is a problem with Windows Server here or what because in test environment (locally with IIS Express) everything works fine.

Comment: @Hrvach where your master page is located ? Inside some folder ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad Master page is located in the root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for your replies. After couple of days of playing I've finally figured out what to do to make everything work.

**JS problems**

I've solved JS problems by adding **ScriptManager** control to the .aspx page and by adding JS files inside it.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smScripts" runat="server">
     <Scripts>
          <asp:ScriptReference Path="JS/jQuery203Min.js"/>
     </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

For some reason CSS files were working "out of the box" so I left them unchanged.

**Image problems**

I've managed to sort images problems out by avoiding hardcoded links to the images and by adding `<%: Page.ResolveUrl("~/Media/Image.png") %>` to the src attribute of the `<img>` tag. I guess I should've done this for everything that I don't want to route. This can be done for CSS files, JS files, everything. However, (even though this should work perfectly) I've experienced some strange problems with JS files and that's the reason for using **ScriptManager**.

**Page links problem**

At first I didn't realize that none of my links was working so I figured that the problem were semi-hardcoded links that, for some reason, don't route properly even though I hardcoded route the same way as defined in **Global.asax** file. I'm still not sure why this isn't working.

The solution for this is to generate links by using `<%: Page.GetRouteUrl("RouteName", new { routeParameter1 = routeParameter1Value, routeParameter2 = routeParameter2Value}) %>` and everyhting will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to sort this by adding `runat=server` attribute and using the tilt(~) before defining the source of the file. For example:

`<link href="~/CSS/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />`

Same applies to `javascript` files.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding runat tag to javascript files caused an error.

Comment: Have you tried `<script src="~/JS/jQuery203Min.js" runat="server"/>`? Note `/>` and no ending `</script>`

Comment: Yes, I have - still the same.I'm really puzzled. 

I have even tried to add .js files to the CSS folder as .css files work as they are supposed to but didn't help either.

Comment: Really bizarre this one as working fine for me. Consider using bundles instead.

Comment: I believe I've found a workaround (after almost 10 days of tweaking, trying, etc.)! :) It seems that adding scripts to the ScriptManager will do the trick - I have to test it a bit, but will let you know!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For any URLs for scripts and styles you need to call ResolveUrl like this:

```
<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/CSS/Style.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. without "~" it can also work but you can add it just to refer the root directory which is always your project solution. So by using Tilde "~" you can properly specify where your css and js files are located.

```
<link href="~/CSS/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="~/JS/jScript.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

Similarly for your images that you have stored in upload folders. You can access it by using

```
<img src="~/Uploads/Images/youImage.gif" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try like below and its worked for me...

```
<script src="JS/jQuery203Min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="JS/jQueryUI1103Min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="CSS/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: That was the first thing I've tried. Unfortunately it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The directories/virtual-directory setup is the likely culprit.

View your page in Google Chrome then "Inspect Element".  Scroll to the top and you include your .JS files.  You can click on them to see what URL they are trying to link to.  More than likely the path is slightly different on the server than your local copy.